# Avoid ignoring a folder in git

Tags: git

I have a two directories named "static" in my project. One with the path "static/" and the other with a path "core/static/". I want to gitignore the first static directory, but I want the "core/static" directory to be tracked.

My current .gitignore file contains:

```
static
!core/static
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `static` to `/static`.

The leading / makes git use an absolute path, this will only ignore the directory specified at that specific absolute location.